# Не отображаются данные RecyclerView в фрагменте после возврата из другого фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Собственно проблема мне напоминает чем то сказку про то как спрятали смерть Кащея в яйце, яйцо в утке, утку в зайце итд.

И так дано есть активность в которой находится фрагмент содержащий TabLayout и ViewPager. Внутри ViewPager находятся два фрагмента с RecyckerView. Когда пользователь делает onClick по Holder я через каллбэк вызываю функцию в активности и подменяю(replace) фрагмент. При нажатии кнопки BackSpace я возвращаюсь к исходному фрагменту, но RecyclerView у меня становится почему то пустым.
Так как кода много, я даю ссылку на github, где он лежит: https://github.com/plesser/Purchase2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/myenv/purchase/purchases/

Основная активность: **PurchasesActivity.java**

Фрагмент который я изначально загружаю **BasketsFragment.java**

Собственно этот фрагмент содержит TabLayout и ViewPager
Сам адаптер ViewPager: **adapters/TabBasketAdapter.java**

Ну и сами фрагменты которые загружаются в ViewPager: **DetailsBasketFragment.java**

**IntoBasketFragment.java** - фрагмент которым я подменяю начальный фрагмент

Сам код:
активность PurchasesActivity

```
public class PurchasesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BasketListener{

private static final String TAG = "purchase:purchase";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragments);

    initFragments();
}

private void initFragments() {
    BasketsFragment fragment = new BasketsFragment();
    fragment.setListener(this);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void openIntoBasketFragment(UUID basketId) {
    Log.d(TAG, basketId.toString());

    IntoBasketFragment fragment = IntoBasketFragment.newInstance(basketId);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void openBasketDialog(UUID basketId) {

}
}
```

Фрагмент BasketsFragment

```
public class BasketsFragment extends Fragment implements BasketListener, BasketEditListener{
private static final String TAG = "purchase:baskets";

TabLayout mTabLayout;
TabBasketAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPagerBasket;

BasketListener mActivityListener;

List<DetailsBasketFragment> mDetailsBasketFragments;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "BasketsFragment created" );
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_baskets, container, false);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_target);
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.open_basket));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.close_basket));

    mPagerBasket = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.basket_pager);

    mPagerBasket.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));

    mDetailsBasketFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    mDetailsBasketFragments.add(DetailsBasketFragment.newInstance("open", mActivityListener));
    mDetailsBasketFragments.add(DetailsBasketFragment.newInstance("close", mActivityListener));

    setupUI();

    mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mPagerBasket.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void setupUI() {


    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new TabBasketAdapter(mDetailsBasketFragments, getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), 2);
        mPagerBasket.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.setDetailsBasketFragments(mDetailsBasketFragments);
        mPagerBasket.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

@Override
public void openIntoBasketFragment(UUID basketId) {

}

@Override
public void openBasketDialog(UUID basketId) {

}

@Override
public void onAddBasket(Basket basket) {

}

@Override
public void onUpdateBasket(Basket basket) {

}

@Override
public void onRemoveBasket(Basket basket) {

}

public void setListener(BasketListener listener) {
    mActivityListener = listener;
}
```

}

адаптер

```
public class TabBasketAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
private static final String TAG = "purchase:tabadapter";

private int mNumberOfTabs;

BasketListener mActivityListener;

List<DetailsBasketFragment> mDetailsBasketFragments;

//DetailsBasketFragment mDetailBasketOpenFragment;
//DetailsBasketFragment mDetailBasketCloseFragment;

public TabBasketAdapter(List<DetailsBasketFragment> detailsBasketFragments, FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
    super(fm);

    //mActivityListener = listener;
    mDetailsBasketFragments = detailsBasketFragments;

    mNumberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
    /*if (mDetailBasketOpenFragment == null) {
        mDetailBasketOpenFragment = DetailsBasketFragment.newInstance("open");
        mDetailBasketOpenFragment.setListener(listener);
    }
    if (mDetailBasketCloseFragment == null) {
        mDetailBasketCloseFragment = DetailsBasketFragment.newInstance("close");
        mDetailBasketCloseFragment.setListener(listener);
    }*/

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, position + "");
    return mDetailsBasketFragments.get(position);
    /*
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return mDetailBasketOpenFragment;
        case 1:
            return mDetailBasketCloseFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }*/
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumberOfTabs;
}

public void setDetailsBasketFragments(List<DetailsBasketFragment> detailsBasketFragments) {
    mDetailsBasketFragments = detailsBasketFragments;
}
}
```

Загружаемые фрагменты в ViewPager

```
public class DetailsBasketFragment extends Fragment implements BasketListener, BasketEditListener{
private static final String TAG = "purchase:detailbasket";
private static final int REQUEST_BASKET = 1;
private static final String BASKET_DIALOG = "basket_dialog";

private static String MODE = "mode";

BasketsAdapter mAdapter;

RecyclerView mBasketsRecyclerView;
TextView mStubTextView;

BasketListener mActivityListener;

FloatingActionButton mAddBasketFloatingActionButton;

MyStorage mStorage;

List<Basket> mBaskets;

String mMode;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detailsbasket, container, false);

    mStorage = MyStorage.newInstance(getActivity());

    mMode = getArguments().getString(MODE);

    mBasketsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.baskets_recyclerview);
    mBasketsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));


    mAddBasketFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.basket_add_floatingbutton);
    if (mMode.equals("close")){
        mAddBasketFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    mAddBasketFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openBasketDialog(null);
        }
    });

    mStubTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stub_textview);

    //--temp
    //TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mode);
    //text.setText(getArguments().getString(MODE));
    //----

    setupUI();

    return view;
}

private void setupUI() {
    mBaskets = mStorage.getBaskets(mMode);

    Log.d(TAG, "setupUI() called " + mBaskets.size());

    if (mBaskets.size() == 0){
        mBasketsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mStubTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mBasketsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStubTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (mAdapter == null){
        mAdapter = new BasketsAdapter(mBaskets, this);
        mBasketsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.setBaskets(mBaskets);
        mBasketsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

public static DetailsBasketFragment newInstance(String mode, BasketListener listener) {
    DetailsBasketFragment detailsBasketFragment = new DetailsBasketFragment();
    detailsBasketFragment.setListener(listener);

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(MODE, mode);

    detailsBasketFragment.setArguments(args);

    return detailsBasketFragment;
}

@Override
public void openIntoBasketFragment(UUID basketId) {
    mActivityListener.openIntoBasketFragment(basketId);
}

@Override
public void openBasketDialog(UUID basketId) {
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    BasketDialog basketDialog = BasketDialog.newIntance(basketId);
    basketDialog.setBasketEditListener(this);
    basketDialog.setTargetFragment(DetailsBasketFragment.this, REQUEST_BASKET);
    basketDialog.show(manager, BASKET_DIALOG);

}

@Override
public void onAddBasket(Basket basket) {
    mStorage.addBasket(basket);
}

@Override
public void onUpdateBasket(Basket basket) {
    mStorage.updateBasket(basket);
}

@Override
public void onRemoveBasket(Basket basket) {
    mStorage.removeBasket(basket);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() called");

    setupUI();
}

public void setListener(BasketListener listener) {
    mActivityListener = listener;
}

}
```

Фрагмент которым я подменяю

```
public class IntoBasketFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "purchase:intobasket";

public IntoBasketFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

RecyclerView mIntoBasketRecyclerView;
TextView mStubTextView;
FloatingActionButton mAddProductBasketFloatingActionButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "IntoBasketFragment");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detailsbasket, container, false);

    return view;
}

private void setupUI() {
}

public static IntoBasketFragment newInstance(UUID basketId){
    IntoBasketFragment intoBasketFragment = new IntoBasketFragment();

    return intoBasketFragment;
}

 }
```

Comment: При возврате из `IntoBasketFragment` в `DetailsBasketFragment` по кнопке "Назад" в первом список становится пустым? Вопрос все же должен содержать код, относящийся к проблеме, неизвестно, что будет с вашим репозиторием через какое-то время и вопрос потеряет всякую ценность для ресурса (люди с аналогичной проблемой не смогут воспользоваться решением). Не нужно добавлять все классы или полностью содержимое классов, только тот код, который относится к проблеме.

Comment: @pavlofff Совершенно верно, список становится пустым. код сейчас добавлю , но в каком именно классе проблема я не знаю.

Comment: @pavlofff Добавил код, спасибо за замечание. Я что то об этом совершенно не подумал

Comment: @pavlofff вечером попробую дебагом пройтись

Comment: @pavlofff onResume не помогло...

Comment: @pavlofff решил

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ на этом сайте в разделе для англоговорящих товарищей: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600156/fragment-in-viewpager-not-restored-after-popbackstack

Проблема решилась заменной getSupportFragmentManager на getChildFragmentManager()
`mAdapter = new TabBasketAdapter(mDetailsBasketFragments, getChildFragmentManager());`